# Fitnesse test pages backup

Tags: fitnesse

How can I make a copy of all my test cases of an older version of fitnesse and restore it into another newer version of fitnesse?

I have tried to copy a folder containing test from one server to another, but newer server doesn't display anything in fitnesse pages.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that FitNesse caches from disk the structure at start up. Assuming that you are putting the files in the right place on disk, I think a restart of FitNesse should find the files.